# order of execution of several fetch calls

Tags: javascript, jwt, es6-promise, fetch-api, asynchronous-javascript

What I'm trying to do is: from my single page application, get data from an API using fetch. If the JWT is expired, ask the API for a new JWT and then renew the request for data.

I tried to implement this with 3 functions: `getData` calls `fetchData`. If `fetchData` returns a `JWT expired` message, a function `getjwt` is called (also from within `getdata`) and *then* (only then) `fetchData` again.

The application calls `getData` (*upon page load - but that's irrelevant here*)

I have a function `getjwt`:

```js
async function getjwt() {
// posts a refresh token and gets a jwt in headers
let adresse = `${baseUrl}/auth/getjwt`
let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

postData(adresse, refresh.value, headers)
.then((response) => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
    jwt.value = response.headers.get('__auth__')  
  }
})
.catch((err) => alert(err))
}
```

and the functions `fetchData` and `getData`:

```js
async function fetchData (url = '', headers = {}) {
  let r = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', 
    mode: 'cors', 
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    credentials: 'include', 
    headers: headers,
    redirect: 'follow', 
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
  })
  return r
}

async function getData(url = '', headers = {}) {
  let r = await fetchData(url, headers)
  if (r.status === 409) {
    console.log("Oh no! My token has expired.")
    getjwt()
    let r = await fetchData(url, headers)
    return r.json()
  } 
  return r.json()
}
```

On purpose, first time fetchData is called, the jwt is expired. `getjwt` is called and the jwt get properly renewed (in a Pinia store). BUT: the order of execution is: `getData` gets called twice, and then `getjwt` is called.

Maybe I'm missing something about asynchroneous operations and Promise, but how can I force `getjwt` to be called and finish getting the new jwt before `getData` is called a second time.

Comment: How is your second call to fetchData in getData different than the first call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the `getJwt` function is that the promise returned by it doesn't wait for the asynchronous operation inside it to finish. As a result, the promise it returns gets resolved *before* `postData` gets completed.

You can fix this by returning the promise from `postData` as shown below:

```
async function getjwt() {
  ...

  return postData(...)
    .then((response) => {
      ...
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      ...
      throw err;
    });
}
```

Adding a `return` before the `postData` call fixes the issue because `return` ensures that the promise returned by the `getJwt` function gets *resolved* to the promise returned by `return postData(...)`. One promise `p1` getting resolved to another promise `p2` simply means that the promise `p1` will wait for `p2` to settle (fulfil or reject). If `p2` fulfils, `p1` fulfils with the same value. If `p2` gets rejected, `p1` also gets rejected with the same rejection reason.

Note the change in the `catch` method. The `throw err` is needed to avoid [implicitly converting the promise rejection into promise fulfilment](https://yousaf.hashnode.dev/common-promise-anti-patterns#heading-converting-promise-rejection-in-to-fulfilment).

As you aren't using the `await` keyword inside the function, you might as well just remove the `async` keyword from the function signature.

And finally, to make it work, you need to `await` the call to the `getJwt` function inside the `getData` function.

```js
async function getData(url = '', headers = {}) {
  ...
  if (r.status === 409) {
    ...
    await getjwt()
    ...
  } 
  ...
}
```

---

I would refactor your code by making the following two improvements:

- Omit the `catch` method call and handle the error in the function that calls the `getJwt` function.
- Use `async-await`

```js
async function getjwt() {
  // posts a refresh token and gets a jwt in headers
  let adresse = `${baseUrl}/auth/getjwt`;
  let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

  const response = await postData(adresse, refresh.value, headers);

  if (response.status === 200) {
    jwt.value = response.headers.get('__auth__');
  }
}
```

Comment: This was not exactly the solution, but it put me on track. Thanks.